# I don't know how to align both of the equations on the left of the minipage

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have to set up a double column layout in the document, so I used 'minipage', inserted the image and then created the right column where I have to insert a system of two equations and after that a short text and then the last equation. The problem is that when I compile the file both equations are partly off the page, as if they were centered in the second column, but I don't know how to align them to the left.

```
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Image.png}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{cases}
            I_{xx}= \frac{1}{12}h^4=6.75\,\text{mm}^4\\
            I_{yy}= I_{xx}\\
        \end{cases}
    \end{equation*}
    
I can now then calculate the maximum strain

\begin{large}
\begin{equation*}
     \begin{aligned}
     \delta_{max}=\frac{1}{3}\frac{FL^3}{EI}=\frac{1}{3}\,\frac{100\cdot1^3}{7\cdot10^{10}\cdot1.06\cdot6.75^{-8}}\simeq7.05467 \,\text{mm}
     \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{large}

\end{minipage}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: It looks like the combined width of the two `minipage` environments is supposed to be `1.2\textwidth`. Is this right?

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which we can compile as it is. Does your document has two column or one, when you like to have in paralele image and equation? `large` is not an environment .... Please consider @Mico comment and  make your question more clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or maybe something like this? (Note that in a two-column setup, LaTeX will place the `figure*` environment at the top of a page.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,demo]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for \num and \qty macros
\sisetup{exponent-product=\cdot,
         group-digits=integer
        }

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Image.png}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
\begin{minipage}{0.55\textwidth}
$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
  I_{xx} &= \tfrac{1}{12}h^4=\qty{6.75}{mm^4}\\
  I_{yy} &= I_{xx}
\end{aligned}
\right.$
    
\medskip
I can now calculate the maximum strain as

\smallskip
$\displaystyle
\delta_{max}
=\frac{1}{3}\frac{\mathit{FL}^3}{\mathit{EI}}
=\frac{1}{3}\,\frac{100\cdot 1^3}{\num{7e10}\times 1.06\cdot6.75^{-8}}
\simeq \qty{7.05467}{mm}
$
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you after?

[image]

If not, please clarify your question, if yes try with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\medskip
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}%
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\[
    \begin{cases}
        I_{xx}= \frac{1}{12}h^4=6.75\,\text{mm}^4\\
        I_{yy}= I_{xx}\\
    \end{cases}
\]
\end{minipage}
\medskip

\noindent%
I can now then calculate the maximum strain

\begingroup
\large
\[
     \begin{aligned}
\delta_{\max}
    & = \frac{1}{3}\frac{FL^3}{EI}      \\
    & = \frac{1}{3}\,\frac{100\cdot1^3}{7\cdot 10^{10}\cdot 1.06\cdot 6.75^{-8}}    \\ 
    & \simeq 7.05467 \,\text{mm}
     \end{aligned}
\]
\endgroup

\lipsum[3-6]
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

- Apparently you have not be willing to clarify your question  (and just pick up the answer which make better guess) an left people here for guessing what you after. Sorry, his is not polite ...
- BTW `large` is not an environment but command which switch font size to `large`, as is shown in above MWE.
- It is still no clear if `EL` and and `EI` are variables or variables are `E`, `L` and `I` as I assumed in above MWE.
- if you like that this image and equation span both lines and consequently insert them in the `figure*` float, you should be aware that this float can appear only on top of the next page from point where it is inserted.
- In the case, that you like to have `figure*` on the same page, where is inserted in document, than you need to add in preamble `\usepackage{stfloats}`. Than it will with option `[t]` appear at top of page and with `[b]` at bottom, if there will be sufficient space (otherwise it will be moved on the bottom of the next page).
- And gain sorry, until you will not clarify above, I would vote to close your question as *unclear*

Just to illustrate aforementioned see test (!) and compare with previous suggestion the following MWE (Minimal Working Example):

```
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{stfloats}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\textbf{Float \texttt{figure*} is inserted here!}
    \begin{figure*} % add [b] if you like to hafe figure* at botom of page
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
\centering
\medskip
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.6\linewidth}
\begin{align*}
    &   \begin{cases}
            I_{xx}= \frac{1}{12}h^4 = \qty{6.75}{\mm^4}\\
            I_{yy}= I_{xx}\\
        \end{cases}
\intertext{I can now then calculate the maximum strain}
\delta_{\max}
    & = \frac{1}{3}\frac{FL^3}{EI}      
      = \frac{1}{3}\,\frac{100 {\cdot} 1^3}{7 {\cdot} 10^{10} {\cdot} 1.06\cdot 6.75^{-8}}
      \simeq \qty{7.05467}{mm}
     \end{align*}
\end{minipage}
    \end{figure*}
    
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The widths sum to 20% more than the global text width, but also using `\columnwidth` would be too much.

You don't need minipages, actually.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{equation*}
\begin{gathered}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth]{example-image}
\end{gathered}
\quad
\begin{cases}
  I_{xx}= \frac{1}{12}h^4=\qty{6.75}{mm^4}\\[2ex]
  I_{yy}= I_{xx}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
I can now then calculate the maximum strain
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\delta_{\mathrm{max}}
&=\frac{1}{3}\frac{FL^3}{EI} \\
&=\frac{1}{3}\,\frac{100\cdot1^3}{7\cdot10^{10}\cdot1.06\cdot6.75^{-8}}
\simeq\qty{7.05467}{mm}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[2-5]

\end{document}
```

Note: `lipsum` is used just to provide context. Also making formulas “larger” is not typographically sound and using `\begin{large}...\end{large}` would not be the correct tool anyway.

I recommend `siunitx` for numbers with units.

[image]

As you see, the formula is sufficiently prominent and there's no need to enlarge it. Please, note `\delta_{\mathrm{max}}` and not `\delta_{max}`.

Never leave a blank line before a math display.